# Writing to file int converted to string

Tags: go, file-writing

I just want simply write to file a string converted from int. But f.WriteString instead of number write a symbols from ASCII code table.

I expected "noReport =  12320 nr3h =  105 nr2h =  162 nr1h =  38 ok =  16899"

But instead got "noReport = 〠 nr3h = i nr2h = ¢ nr1h = & ok = 䈃"

Comment: Please show us a minimal, complete, verifiable example of your code that has the described issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://play.golang.org/p/QAXJ4aJBy3

```
fmt.Printf("os.StdOut is %T\n", os.Stdout)
os.Stdout.WriteString("noReport = 12320 nr3h = 105 nr2h = 162 nr1h = 38 ok = 16899 \n")
os.Stdout.WriteString("12320")

//Output
//os.StdOut is *os.File
//noReport = 12320 nr3h = 105 nr2h = 162 nr1h = 38 ok = 16899 
//12320
```

Works fine for me.

Give us your code, please.

**UDP**

string(noReport), noReport is integer right? Thats expected behavior.

Use [strconv.Itoa](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Itoa)(noReport).

```
noReport := 12320
nr3h := 105
nr2h := 162
nr1h := 38
ok := 16899
os.Stdout.WriteString("noReport = "+ strconv.Itoa(noReport) + " nr3h = " + strconv.Itoa(nr3h)+ " nr2h = "+ strconv.Itoa(nr2h)+ " nr1h = "+ strconv.Itoa(nr1h) + " ok = "+ strconv.Itoa(ok)+ "\n")
```

Or evanmcdonnal's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37620716/6248842).

Comment: f, err := os.Create("/tmp/mt_report")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
defer f.Close()
w := bufio.NewWriter(f)
w.WriteString("noReport = "+ string(noReport) + " nr3h = " + string(nr3h)+ " nr2h = "+ string(nr2h)+ " nr1h = "+ string(nr1h) + " ok = "+ string(ok)+ "\n")

Answer (score 2):

To get a string with your ints I recommend using `fmt.Sprintf`

It would be something like this;

```
s := fmt.Sprintf("noReport = %d nr3h = %d nr2h = %d nr1h = %d ok = 16899", 12320, 162, 38)
```

which will assign the value `"noReport = 12320 nr3h = 105 nr2h = 162 nr1h = 38 ok = 16899"` to `s`.